# How are un-buffered video streams started halfway

Tags: http, video, youtube

I was recently playing a video on YouTube, and a thought came to my mind. As videos are played, a user can skip ahead in the video and the video just resumes at that point without any trouble.

What I can't seem to find is how this works, I know that when I request a file through HTTP it downloads the entire thing, so starting a binary stream halfway through the video doesn't seem possible using HTTP. Is there any RFC or related document on how browsers do this?

Thank you

Comment: It's my understanding that videos served through the web are separated into smaller files, so they can be downloaded depending on the time the user requests. There is also the concept of "media server", a computer that specializes in manipulating and providing access to media files like videos and sound files. I don't have an exact answer to your question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different technologies but they all essentially allow you specific an offset in the video and then download a 'chunk' from there.

The simple way to do this is with byte ranges and HTTP progressive download 0 there is an RFC which covers this:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233

A similar but slightly more complex mechanism is behind the various adaptive bit rate protocols, such as HLS, MPEG-DASH, Smooth-streaming etc. These protocols break a video into multiple chunks (e..g 10 second long segments) and also create several different encoding of the video each at different bit rates.

The client can then request the next chunk based on current network conditions - if the network is busy or if the client is using a low band witch connection it can request the next chunk from a low bit rate encoding of the video. If network connectivity improves then it can request from progressively higher bit rates until it reaches the maximum.

You can see this in action if you look at the 'stats for nerds' available in YouTube if you right click on the video - look at the connection speed graph.

This mechanism also means the client can request chunks from further ahead (or behind) than the current position in the video - so long as it is not live obviously!

It also allows faster start up if you do jump ahead as the playback can start from a lower bit rate which is faster to download and work up to the higher bit rate again. You can often see this when playing around with services like Netflix - if you jump ahead it may be lower quality for a little time initially.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube stores the videos in several chunks. Once each chunk completes its download, you can play that chunk of video. Think of them as individual split videos.

When you try to jump into the middle, they will start downloading the necessary chunk of video and start playing. Therefore, you can jump to the middle.